# How to link .so using abspath?

Tags: gcc, linker, clang, shared-libraries, ld

I use the following command to link an object to a .so file. (On Mac, but the question should be relevant to Linux as well)

```
$ clang main.o -L../sds -lsds -o main.exe
```

The abspath of `libsds.so` is not found in the executable. But `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` is in abspath. Why one is in abspath but the other is not? How to make `libsds.so` in abspath in the executable? Thanks.

```
$ otool -L main.exe 
main.exe:
    libsds.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
```

Comment: Is main.exe ELF?

Comment: On Mac, it is not.

Comment: Is `libsds.so` in the same directory as main.exe?